# Scoping date attribute for this week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to scope all of my Products for this week, so it should show all the products leading up to whichever day of the week.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :purchase_date

   def self.this_weeks
    where("purchase_date >= ?", Date.at_beginning_of_week - Date.at_end_of_week)
  end

  create_table :products do |t|
      t.date :purchase_date
  end
end
```

This gives me an error though:

```
undefined method `at_beginning_of_week'
```

What do I need to correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

at_beginning_of_week has been removed in Rails 3. You should use [beginning_of_week](http://apidock.com/rails/Date/beginning_of_week) but, be careful, it's an instance method. So you have to do something like:

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week
```

Furthermore, you can use a range and make your query very nice to read:

```
where(:purchase_date => Date.today.beginning_of_week..Date.today.end_of_week)
```

Comment: Thank you for both answers, I will be using the new readable way.