# How to scope last week by Date object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scoping date attribute for this week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505997/scoping-date-attribute-for-this-week)

I am trying to scope all of my Products for this week, so it should show all the products leading up to whichever day of the week.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :purchase_date

   def self.last_week # All prices of last week.
      where(:purchase_date => 1.week.ago)
   end

   create_table :products do |t|
      t.date :purchase_date
   end
end
```

This code renders nothing in the view though so what do I need to correct?

---

**ANSWER**

For some reason I had to add `advance(:days => -1)` to in order to also retrieve Monday as well. You may not have to do this though.

```
def self.last_week
    where(:purchase_date => 1.week.ago.beginning_of_week.advance(:days => -1)..1.week.ago.end_of_week).order("purchase_date desc")
end
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I had to do the `advance(:days => -1)` because of the Time zone I am in. I got rid of this by making sure I'm in my own Time zone. So now it can be normal as it should be:

```
def self.last_week
  where(:purchase_date => 1.week.ago.beginning_of_week..1.week.ago.end_of_week)
end
```

And it should work correctly ONLY if you go by the default Rails Time zone or you config your own:

app/config/environment/development.rb

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 12):

This should do the trick:

```
scope :last_week, lambda { where("purchase_date >= :date", :date => 1.week.ago) } 

scope :past_week, lambda { where("purchase_date >= :start_date AND purchase_date <= :end_date", {:start_date => 1.week.ago, :end_date => 1.day.ago }) }
```

Comment: yes for the date to be updated properly each time

Comment: Could this go inside of the defined method?

Comment: it can go inside the method, but you won't need the lambda then. I still believe you should keep scope

Comment: I get a `stack level too deep` for some reason as an error.

Comment: just tried the scope in console, it's fine. You sure it's from here?

Comment: Yeah sorry. It is working but also I noticed its showing the date of the 12th of December when it should be 5th to 11th(Sunday), is there a way around this?

Comment: Get the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid SQLite3::SQLException: near "&": syntax error`. I tried to replace the `&&` with `and` but that didn't work either.

Comment: sorry, `&&` should be `AND`. See doc here, para 2.2.1: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions

Comment: It gives me dates 9th (friday last week) to 13th (yesterday).

Comment: simply adjust with `n.days.ago` :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5859/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-wrbg)